# Savings emails as individual files using Procmail

Tags: email, filter, procmail

I installed Getmail to retrieve emails from another email server and Procmail to filter the incoming emails. (I am running Debian/Squeeze.)

The recipe I created has this code:

```
:0:
* ^TO_myemailaddress@domain.com
Xyz
```

I thought this will make sure that all incoming emails will be saved in `~/Maildir/Xyz/` as individual files. Instead, it seems to be creating a file called `Xyz` (not a directory) inside `~/Maildir/` and appending new emails to the same file.

How do I save incoming mails as individual files to a folder, instead of a single file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top level of `procmail` recipes are reserved for assignment of `procmail` variables. Add the following to the top of your procmail recipe.

```
MAILDIR="$HOME/Maildir/"
```

When defining where the mail should be delivered, you have defined Xyz as a file, not a directory. It should instead read:

```
:0:
* ^TO_myemailaddress@domain.com
Xyz/
```

`procmail` is extremely powerful with many options. I'm always amazed at what it can do.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. (I had set `MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir/` earlier, but wasn't sure if I should add the forward slash at the of the folder name.)